# Python Pandas groupby and returning result to original Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas

I created a DataFrame using Pandas with 6 years of monthly data.  I then created a DataFrame with only the first 5 years of that data.  I returned the max values and min values by month over the 5 years for each month (Jan - Dec).

This is so I can plot the the previous 5 year range on the current year.

This is how I did it below but it a little verbose.  I would like any suggestion to make it cleaner.

```
DF = pd.Series(np.random.randn(72), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=72, freq='M'))


DF5y = DF['2000':'2004']

by = lambda x: lambda y: getattr(y, x)

Max5y = DF5y.groupby([by('month')]).max()
Min5y = DF5y.groupby([by('month')]).max()

MaxbyMonthDates = pd.Series(Max5y.values, index=pd.date_range('1/1/2005', periods=12, freq='M'))

MinbyMonthDates = pd.Series(Min5y.values, index=pd.date_range('1/1/2005', periods=12, freq='M'))


keys1 = ['DF', 'MaxbyMonthDates' , 'MinbyMonthDates']

DF_5yr_Range = pd.concat([DF, MaxbyMonthDates, MinbyMonthDates], axis=1, keys=keys1)


DF_5yr_Range.tail(15)
Out[13]: 
                  DF  MaxbyMonthDates  MinbyMonthDates
2004-10-31 -0.154463              NaN              NaN
2004-11-30 -1.085822              NaN              NaN
2004-12-31 -0.462416              NaN              NaN
2005-01-31  2.422458         0.439354         0.439354
2005-02-28 -1.033706         2.308936         2.308936
2005-03-31 -0.020724         0.333981         0.333981
2005-04-30 -0.901237         1.810083         1.810083
2005-05-31 -0.890278         1.538757         1.538757
2005-06-30 -1.412531         1.416770         1.416770
2005-07-31  1.640020         1.903341         1.903341
2005-08-31  0.897491         2.001736         2.001736
2005-09-30 -0.690588         0.798006         0.798006
2005-10-31 -0.768929         1.276541         1.276541
2005-11-30 -1.618866         0.347229         0.347229
2005-12-31  0.160188        -0.046892        -0.046892
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.Series(np.random.randn(72), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=72, freq='M'))

grouped = df.groupby(df.index.map(lambda x: x.month))
mnthmax, mnthmin = grouped.transform(max), grouped.transform(min)
df2 = pd.concat([df, mnthmax, mnthmin], axis=1)
df2.columns = ['data', 'max', 'min']

df2['2001'].plot()
```

giving, for eg. 2001:

[image]

Comment: Yes this is very clean.  The only thing is you are returning a max min values over the whole data frame. I like this idea when I plot years other than the last year.  I was returning NA's to make sure people don't mistake what years the range information is for so I will have to make a clear legend on the chart.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does. Is that not what you're looking for? Sorry, I'm not clear whether you would like me to revise my answer to generate something else.

Comment: You do not need to change the answer.  It works great you just came at it a little different so that is good.  Do you know if I can use a groupby with a date range on the index?  for example mnthmax2 = ['2000':'2004']grouped.max()  which does not work.

Comment: One more thing I like you chart settings it seems to look a lot like ggplot the R package did you set this up and if so what is a good resource to get the setting to match?  Thanks!

Comment: Great. I think you'll need to slice the original dataset before grouping, eg. `df['2001':'2003'].groupby(df['2001':'2003'].index.map(lambda x: x.month)).transform(max)`. I used the [`seaborn`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/) library for that plot, which builds on top of `matplotlib`.

Comment: Very nice thanks for both.  Looking forward to checking out the Seaborn library.

Comment: Would you be so kind to post the code for the plot too?

Comment: Sure, I've updated with working code example producing attached plot.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I have download and started working with Seaborn it is nice, again thanks for the tip.